# Checking for null returned items

Tags: c#, linq

Currently i am returning a list of items all have a date range. Some of the appointments have expired and others have not happened yet. I am displaying the appointments that have not expired yet. But i want to check if all appoinments have expired then show the first item.

```
var curApt = myAppts.Where(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow).First();
```

If `myAppts.Where(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow) == null`

```
var curApt = myAppts.First();
```

how can i structure this so i consider both cases?

Comment: Just to add information, .First() will throw an Exception if there aren't any values (i.e. there are no apartments with an EndTime after now) rather than returning Null.  Like all of the answers say, use .FirstOrDefault() (or if appropriate, .FirstOrDefaut(where clause)).  You use .First() if you know for certain that every time this will ever run there will be at least one value evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) and the [null coalescing operator (`??`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
var curApt = myAppts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow)
             ?? myAppts.First();
```

However, you could make this even less exception prone if you have a default value to show if there is no appointments at all, you could chain the null coalescing operator for that:

```
var curApt = myAppts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow)
             ?? myAppts.FirstOrDefault() ?? yourDefault;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) method:

```
var curApt = myAppts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow);
```

To find the first one which is not expired, or `null` if all appointments are expired. So to default it to the first appointment in that case, you can use this:

```
var curApt = myAppts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow);
if (curApt == null) 
{
    curApt = myAppts.First();
}
```

Or you can use use the [null-coalescing operator (`??`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for brevity:

```
var curApt = myAppts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow)
          ?? myAppts.First();
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the long forgotten overload of FirstOrDefault that takes a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [`.FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) here:

```
var curApt = myAppts.Where(d => d.Appt.EndTime > DateTime.UtcNow).FirstOrDefault();
if (curApt == null) {
    // no expirations
    curApt = myAppts.First();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use FirstOrDefault() instead of First(), and after the first statement check if curApt is null, and if so do the second statement.